# Extract multiple records from raw text using open AI API function calls

Tags: open-ai, chatgpt, gpt-3

Trying to extract records from pdf. The plan was to convert pdf data to raw text and use open AI api calls to extract the data in a desired format (csv). This is because the pdf data is very unstructured. While I do get records back in the output, I get only the 1st one from every page when there are multiple records. What can I do to get all records back in the desired format. Further I use a code to get back a csv , but the issue is with API response and not handling JSON to CSV
Raw data : https://pastebin.com/fKKyJCTB

```
functions = [
    {
        "name": "extract_permit_data",
        "description": "Extract data from a permit record and add it to the database.",
        "parameters": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "permit_number": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "description": "The unique permit number."
                },
                "permit_type": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "description": "The type of permit."
                },
                "address": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "description": "The address associated with the permit."
                },
                "valuation": {
                    "type": "number",
                    "description": "The valuation associated with the permit."
                },
                "applied_date": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "format": "date",
                    "description": "The date the permit was applied for."
                },
                "permit_subtype": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "description": "The subtype of the permit."
                },
                "parcel_number": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "description": "The parcel number associated with the permit."
                },
                "total_fees": {
                    "type": "number",
                    "description": "The total fees associated with the permit."
                },
                "issued_date": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "format": "date",
                    "description": "The date the permit was issued."
                },
                "status": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "description": "The status of the permit."
                },
                "description": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "description": "The description of the permit."
                },
                "subdivision": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "description": "The subdivision associated with the permit."
                },
                "total_paid": {
                    "type": "number",
                    "description": "The total amount paid for the permit."
                },
                "contractor": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "description": "The contractor associated with the permit."
                },
                "contractor_address": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "description": "The contractor's address."
                },
                "contractor_phone_number": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "description": "The contractor's phone number."
                },
                "owner_name": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "description": "The name of the owner associated with the permit."
                },
                "owner_address": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "description": "The owner's address."
                },
                "owner_phone_number": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "description": "The owner's phone number."
                },
                "applicant_name": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "description": "The name of the applicant."
                },
                "applicant_address": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "description": "The applicant's address."
                },
                "applicant_phone_number": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "description": "The applicant's phone number."
                }
            },
            "required": ["permit_number", "permit_type", "address", "valuation", "applied_date", "permit_subtype", "parcel_number", "total_fees", "issued_date", "status", "description", "subdivision", "total_paid", "contractor", "contractor_address", "contractor_phone_number", "owner_name", "owner_address", "applicant_name", "applicant_address", "applicant_phone_number"],
        },
    }
] 
messages = [
                    {"role": "system", "content": "You are a helpful assistant that extracts all solar permit records information and other details from raw text containing multiple permits indicated by permit unique permit numbers into JSON for a database."},
                    {"role": "user", "content": 'Extract each record with permit numbers, permit status, permit address, contractor/applicant,owner, issue date, permit type, sub-type, valuation , work description , Storage/Battery Manufacturer Name and kw rating from raw text fpr each record: ' + text}
]

# Call the model
response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
                    model='gpt-3.5-turbo-0613',
                    functions=functions,
                    messages=messages,
                    temperature=0
                )
# Get result
result = response.choices[0]['message']['function_call']['arguments']'''
```